# Get the right part of URL in ASP MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a domain where I put many applications. My domains is in smarter ASP. I create a folder for each application.

Then the URI path like it to the next

How to get the right and left part of URL. By example:

http://siteofsites/site/controller/action?parameters

Where:

- "siteofsites" is a domain.
- "site" is my web app.

I need put in a variable.

```
var leftpart=http://siteofsites/site/
var rigthpart=/controller/action?parameters.
```

Is there a way to get this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get application path without using httpcontext. (asp.net)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2409540/get-application-path-without-using-httpcontext-asp-net)

Comment: No it´'s not sim, i need generated the url, this ex. is for the current controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Request.Url` which is available in the View and Controller.

```
@Request.Url.AbsolutePath  
-> "controller/action?parameters"

@Request.Url.Scheme + "://" + @Request.Url.Host
-> "http://siteofsites/site"
```

Comment: I solucionate about left part with this   var base_url = Request.Url.Scheme + "://" + Request.Url.Authority + Request.ApplicationPath.TrimEnd('/') + "/"; the rigth part using replace function